# Bad performance and odd behavior since Windows 10 Creators Update

Tags: performance, gaming, windows-10-v1703, fps

Recently I've had to update my PC to the new Windows 10 Creators Update.

After it was installed, I jumped right into a game and immediately noticed some low frames. I did a disk cleanup, hoping it would help, but no. Without further thinking I just did a complete clean install of the new CU. I thought problems would be fixed. I installed my programs, games and drivers and the first thing I noticed was odd behavior as regards to my overclocks. My GPU OC no longer worked at all; whenever I did the slightest OC I would instantly get weird screen tears on my desktop. My CPU OC also seemed a little unstable even though I haven't used different OC values.

So now to my real problem, the bad in-game performance. Even with the clean installation of the CU, I still have lower FPS than usual. Some games have more obvious performance decreases than others but it's definitely noticeable in most games. Overwatch used to stay completely locked at 60 fps but now it stutters pretty often with frames as low as 30.  GTA 5 ran with a nice 40/50 fps most of the time and never dipping below 30.  Now it's at 28 fps most of the time. DOOM may even be the worst since the update. That game ran 60 fps almost constant, even in the more demanding scenes. Now it runs 40 fps, even in the first mission which isn't demanding at all.

Now the reason I'm posting this is because I'm clueless on what to do. I've tried everything I could think of but nothing worked so far. These are the things I have already done:

- Disabled Game DVR
- Disabled Game Mode
- Disabled Fullscreen Optimization (which seemed to make the FPS worse
  than it already was)
- Used the default clock speed (which also made the performance worse
  (obviously))
- Updated my graphics drivers
- Checked for Windows updates (which where already up-to-date)
- Used both the default Power Options and my own (which didn't make an
  obvious difference)
- Did a Disk Cleanup
- Did a disk defragmentation
- Checked my temperatures (which were fine)

Again, nothing I've tried worked. The performance stays bad. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require me to buy new hardware (obviously). Games have worked well before so I just ask for a solution to make my PC work as it used to. Going back to a previous build can't be done because I clean installed my OS which got rid of the Anniversary Update, so now Roll Back is not available.

Comment: It would be good to know the specs of the computer.

Comment: Sounds like a display driver problem.  "Going back to a previous build can't be done because I clean installed my OS which got rid of the Anniversary Update, so now Roll Back." - You can always do a clean install of 1607 if you wanted, but you would be forced to go to 1703, eventually.  Your performance problems are not because of 1703 though.

Comment: Possibly related: [Windows 10 Creators Update (1703) – very low performance on high-end laptop](https://superuser.com/q/1200171/150988)

Comment: If it isn't the update, then what is it? I have tried about everything, but mu FPS is considerably lower then with the previous build. How are you able to download 1607 anyway, It's not on the Microsoft website anymore so what are you aiming at, if I may ask?

Comment: you can get it from this page: https://tb.rg-adguard.net/dl.php?go=Win10_1607_English_x64.iso&edition_id=244 this generates links to Microsoft servers. Also try the latest Insider Build, the Fall Creators Update gets finished soon. Maybe they have fixed it there and can fix it if you report it during Bug Bash.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Hope this works, the download seems sketchy but it probably is fine lol. Indeed hope they fix this problem. It's obviously related to the CU, maybe in combination with my hardware and drivers.

Comment: does the download work? is win10 more stable in 1607 compared to 1703?

Comment: So I have tried the 1607 build. To my biggest surprise it indeed wasn't the CU. At least my PC is still behaving the same. I have found that an older driver got rid of one of the odd behaviors I experience but despite it my performance is still very bad. My gpu OC is also still having issues where I have weird flickering whenever I use 2 monitors. People were talking about a GPU flash via the bios. I doubt this will fix things but it indeed could very likely be a gpu drivers issue. Again temps are normal.

Comment: which GPU do you use?

Comment: I use the R9 270 MSI OC edition currently set to 950Mhz, the default set by MSI, previously always able to OC to 975Mhz or even past that.

Comment: have you checked the temperatures (GPU, CPU)? maybe you get overheating and both begin to throttle

Comment: Both seem fine, GPU at 65 degrees celsius max, CPU 49 defrees celsius thermal margin under load of GTA V, I have a twin cooler MSI and a custom coolermaster cooler for my CPU, the temps usually tend to be really good under load, although I doubt the cpu temperatures are accurate. They seem way too low. I heard things about amd processors not displaying the right temps. I currently use iverdrive any program that works best for this?

Comment: post all your HW + driver information in the question so that we can see which HW you use

Comment: -R9 270 @ 950Mhz with latest drivers installed -A10-7850k @4.2Ghz along with a good enough cooler -12Gb DDR3 memory @ 1600Mhz -500Gb HDD and a 3TB HDD -ASUS motherboard with updated bios

Comment: So i'm still having problems although I think I fixed DOOM now, don't know how though